# Vaadin 8.3 session fail after press key F5

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin8

i am use Jwt in vaadin session, and when press F5 i have problem [Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSqz2.png)

```
 private void onLogin(LoginForm.LoginEvent loginEvent) {
    String enteredUsername = loginEvent.getLoginParameter("username");
    String enteredPassword = loginEvent.getLoginParameter("password");

    AuthenticationResponse response = apiExecutorService.doAdminAuthentication(enteredUsername, enteredPassword);

    if (response != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(response.getAccessToken())) {
        // Put token into session params
        String test = response.getAccessToken();
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("access_token", response.getAccessToken());
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute("refresh_token", response.getRefreshToken());

        Notification...

        // Wait and redirect to admin page
        Page current = Page.getCurrent();
        notification.addDetachListener(event -> current.setLocation("/admin"));
```

Comment: You don't treat exceptions. You're missing any `try/catch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this crutch:

`addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("refresh", ShortcutAction.KeyCode.F5, null) {
            @Override
            public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
                refreshGrid();
            }
        });`